# How to apply machine learning to a csv file to predict future values

Tags: pandas, datetime, machine-learning, scikit-learn, predict

I'm curious about ML and I wonder if some of you guys could help me getting started.

I have a dataset in a csv format like this:

| Date | First | Second | Third |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-30 | 5402 | 8694 | 8648 |
| 2022-12-29 | 3804 | 8529 | 6690 |
| 2022-12-28 | 3192 | 2779 | 2166 |

I want to predict first, second, and third values in the future time e.g. `2022-12-31`.

What kind of algorithm is suitable to do this job? How do I have to implement this in my Jupyter notebook? Any example and/or reference of this problem will be so helpful to me. This is for predicting a 4-digit lottery game.

I have let panda to read my csv file and set it to a variable named "dataset"

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

dataset=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/data.csv")

dataset['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dataset.Date)
```

Comment: I think the question is to broad for SO and will probably be closed. However my suggestion is to start by plotting the number against the time and see what they look like. Different ML-algorithms are usually suitable for different type of problems and to know what type of algoritm you need we need to know what type of data it is. Is it very noisy? Does it look linear? Does it look completely random?

Comment: Hi Remsly  As Cleared said, this question needs more focus. But briefly: lottery numbers cannot be predicted (unless someone is manipulating them a predictable way). Think of it this way: for a fair 6-sided dice, you cannot predict *which* number will occur, but you can be sure that one of six numbers will occur. For a biased 6-sided dice, one side may have higher probability, so the optimal strategy is to pick the biased side.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are predicting the trend of the random winning number so linear regression would be the ideal choice for this.